# How do I take a UTF8 encoded version of data carried in an NSString and return it to NSData?

Tags: php, ios, encoding, zip

I'm trying to transmit a zip archive between a server and a device, and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  To make life easy, I've currently uploaded the file using PHPMyAdmin's upload features in an effort to reduce possible encoding issues.  I've also confirmed that the file in the database is correct by creating a quick script that serves it up as a download -- other than having to rename the file to a .zip file (because I didn't specify a filename), it works perfectly.

The server uses the following code to serve up the zipped data.  ($ad is an object, with getZippedHTML() doing exactly what it sounds like: it recovers the actual binary data)  I use UTF8 encoding to avoid an issue where json_encode won't print direct binary data for an unkown.

```
$response['ad']=utf8_encode($ad->getZippedHTML();
print  json_encode($response);
```

On the iOS side, I attempt to decode the data with:

```
NSString *zipString=[serverResponse valueForKey:@"ad"];
NSData *zipData=[zipString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Test retrieved data
[zipData writeToFile:zipPath atomically:YES];
```

However, the file that gets written to disk doesn't appear to be a valid zip archive -- unzip utilities are unable to use it.  I've tracked down the issue to the fact that I'm not decoding the data with dataUsingEncoding, but rather encoding it all over again.

How do I take a UTF8 encoded string and reverse that to NSData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
- (BOOL)getBytes:(void *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount 
    usedLength:(NSUInteger *)usedBufferCount encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding 
    options:(NSStringEncodingConversionOptions)options range:(NSRange)range 
    remainingRange:(NSRangePointer)leftover
```

Passing a C pointer to the buffer. You can get the length of the data given the encoding with the method:

```
- (NSUInteger)lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

You can then create an NSData object with:

```
+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
```

There might be a more convenient means of accomplishing this, but I believe these methods will get you where you want to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  I use the second function to get the length, create a buffer, then use the first function to load the data into the buffer.  Unfortunately, the end result of the NSData created using the third function you've suggested still doesn't output a useable zip.

Comment: Is it possible that the json encoding on the php side is doing something to the data, for example, escaping certain bytes, so that the data coming over the pipe is malformed?

Comment: That's actually what I wound up suspecting.  Unfortunately, diagnosing that is a bit beyond my immediate skills, and there is a small time crunch going on.  I wound up scrapping the use of JSON and just serving the file up directly, which works.  I can't serve up meta-data at the same time, but I don't strictly speaking need to (even if it would be more convenient in some ways).

Comment: I don't think it's too uncommon to isolate metadata from the actual data contents. It's a normal enough way to serve a file, with metadata like type and size going in the http headers instead of the content itself.

Comment: I didn't think about using headers to convey custom meta-data, but I suppose that's workable enough.  I'm not planning to serve this up to browsers anyways, after all.  Oh, and accepting your answer because even though it didn't work, as far as I can tell it SHOULD have worked, suggesting the issue is elsewhere.